# Parsing nested JSON in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, nested

I have been trying to parse nested JSON data and below is my code

```
var string = '{"key1": "value", "key2": "value1", "Key3": {"key31":"value 31"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(obj.key1)
console.log(obj[0]);
```

And this is the output

```
$ node try.js 
value
undefined
```

Why I am getting undefined for `obj[0]`? How to get value in this case, and also for nested key `key31`?

**Update**
Now with the help from @SergeyK and others, I have modified my above code as follows

```
var string = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": {"key31":"value 31"}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(string);
var array = Object.keys(obj)

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i], obj[array[i]]);
}
```

And the output is as follows

```
$ node try.js 
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 { key31: 'value 31' }
```

But for `{"key31":"value 31"}` how would I access key `key31` and get its value `value 31`?

Comment: What value would you expect for `obj[0]`?

Comment: It is an hash, not an array. What do you expect when you write `obj[0]`?

Comment: JSON **Objects** (`{ ... }`) use key based indexes, which means if you want to get `"value"` you need to reference it by it's key: `obj["key1"]` or `obj.key1`, you can only used numeric indexes when using **Arrays**: `[ .. ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't access named object property by index. You can use `obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]`

**Edit:**

As @smarx explained in the comments, this answer is not suitable for direct access to the specific property by index due to `Object.keys` is unordered, so it is only for cases, when you need to loop keys/values of object.

**Example:**

```
var string = '{"key1": "value", "key2": "value1", "Key3": {"key31":"value 31"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
var keysArray = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
   var key = keysArray[i]; // here is "name" of object property
   var value = obj[key]; // here get value "by name" as it expected with objects
   console.log(key, value);
}
// output:
// key1 value
// key2 value1
// Key3 { key31: 'value 31' }
```

Comment: I don't think `Object.keys` guarantees any particular ordering, so there's no way to predict which key you would be accessing here, right? (So I can't see how this code would be useful.)

Comment: There was nothing about ordering in the question if i have no any misunderstanding. It is suitable for looping trough object properties, for "getting value", not for direct access to the specific property.

Comment: The snippet you shared will give a random value from the object. (Random in the sense that it can't be predicted.) Do you actually think that will help the person who asked this question?

Comment: Snippet i shared just shows how to access values, as it was requested. You can also use `Object.keys(obj)[0]` a key name, depends what do you want to do, right?

Comment: How do I loop keys values of the JSON object as I would be getting JSON object and would have no clue of the Key names

Comment: Thanks SergeyK. But can't we read it raw as a JSON instead of converting it to array ?

Comment: We do not converting it to array, we just get array of object's "property names", with `Object.keys()` method. Then we iterate through this array, so for every name we will get every value "by name" `var value = obj[key]`.

Comment: Thanks I read through my array of objects and I am able to get key value of top level i.e key1, key2 and key3 using obj[1] ... obj[3], but how do I get a value for "key31" as I am not able to do obj[2][0].

Comment: You can do it going through the "levels" with recursive function i think.

Comment: @Sergeyk, please can you guide. Thanks

Comment: You must consider that this is only a concept of usage, not the bulletproof recipe.

Comment: Thanks for your help @SergeyK

Answer (score 2):

When you tries to access

```
 console.log(obj[0]);
```

You are actually trying to refer element at very first memory location in an array, but `var string` is a hash not array.
Thats why you are getting `undefined`.

Comment: You mean "`obj` is an object not an array." `string` is a `string`. :-)

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake to consider json as array

Answer (score 2):

console.log(obj[0]) will display its value only if obj is an array. For example:

```
var obj = ["value","value2"];
console.log(obj[0]) --> value
```

With an object, you need to use the key as identifier.

For nested key key31:

```
console.log(obj.Key3.key31) --> value 31
```

Hope to be helpfull

Answer (score 2):

`console.log(obj[0]);` is giving `undefined` because `obj is not an array`. `obj[0]` will work only if obj is an array as we are accessing the `first index` element from an array.

**Example :**

```
var obj = ["val1","val2","val3"];

console.log(obj[0]); // val1
```

**As per requirement :**

```
var string = '{"key1": "value", "key2": "value1", "Key3": {"key31":"value 31"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
var keyArray = Object.keys(obj); // key1
console.log(obj[(keyArray[0])]); // value
```

**working fiddle :**

https://jsfiddle.net/kbwbspnk/

For nested property value you have to use **`.`** operator.

```
console.log(obj.Key3.key31); // value 31
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Actually I would be getting a JSON object and I would have no clue of key names.

Comment: @JoelDivekar Ok as per your requirement you can try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you want `obj[0]` to do, so I can't help with that.

To get the value for key31, use `obj.Key3.key31`, which, when logged, should yield `value 31`.

Comment: That was my mistake smarx as I was considering JSON object as an array

Answer (score 0):

your variable (String) is not array its object in above case and you can not access using indexing like 0,1,2... ,you can access this with its key value name like key1,key2...

example:
    obj['key1'] 
    $ value
    obj['Key3']['key31'] 
    $ value 31

Comment: I think you mean "`obj` is not an array. It's an object." (`string` is a `string`.)